# Which is the better "if statement" to use in C#

Tags: c#, readability

Both these methods work, however which is better method to use out of the following:

```
PlaceHolder PH = ctl.PlaceHoldNu == 1 ? (PlaceHolder)Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") : (PlaceHolder)FindControl("PlaceHolder" + ctl.PlaceHoldNu);
```

Or

```
           PlaceHolder PH;
                    if (ctl.PlaceHoldNu == 1)
                        PH = (PlaceHolder)Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolder1");
                    else
                        PH = (PlaceHolder)FindControl("PlaceHolder" + ctl.PlaceHoldNu);
```

Comment: That's purely a matter of taste, since the compiler (with optimization enabled) will most likely produce the same IL code for both.

Comment: The first is more succinct, and one (most of this time) strives to write code that is not unnecessarily verbose. In light of this, the first (in my opinion) is the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another solution would be:

```
PlaceHolder PH = ctl.PlaceHoldNu == 1
    ? (PlaceHolder)Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") 
    : (PlaceHolder)FindControl("PlaceHolder" + ctl.PlaceHoldNu);
```

This solutions uses a minimum of lines but maintains readability.

Comment: I wonder too. Although it isn't "another solution", this format is offered by Resharper, so it must have some popularity.

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of taste. However, if they get too long, I would prefer the second. But before that happens, I think this looks nice:

```
PlaceHolder PH =
    ctl.PlaceHoldNu == 1
    ? (PlaceHolder)Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolder1")
    : (PlaceHolder)FindControl("PlaceHolder" + ctl.PlaceHoldNu);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best one is the one you prefer using.

They will compile down to the same thing, so it depends on the context. Which one makes the intent of what you are trying to do more clear?

Answer (score 0):

For this case I like the first one, as I feel it's more readable and concise.

A bit more complex than this, and your second approach will be the preferred one.

But this is just as much your own taste than *correct*

Answer (score 0):

I generally only use the conditional operator on assignments (like you have done), but only when they're simple and easy to read.

The length of you assignments would make me favour the second for readability.

Basically whichever is easiest to parse if you imagine you've never looked at the code before.